# Mesh shakes in three.js when position (x, y or z) is too large number

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, largenumber

I need a scene (universe), where the distances between meshes are very large numbers (for example 10^15). But the mesh with a large position (x, y or z) shakes.  I tried `logarithmicDepthBuffer`, but it doesn't help.

I can't reduce the distance because there are meshes with a distance of 1000 km and also 1 000 000 light years. Is there any way to fix it? Here is [example](https://jsfiddle.net/ukLvpfdt/14/).

```html
<html>

<head>
 <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
 logarithmicDepthBuffer: true
});

renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

cube.position.x = Math.pow(10, 15) // Very large position x.
cube.add(camera)
scene.add(cube);

camera.position.z = 3;

function animate() {
 requestAnimationFrame(animate);
 renderer.render(scene, camera);
 cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
}

animate();
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There are numeric limits.. you probably will either need to scale all your units down by a factor of 10 or 100...

OR change your coordinate system so that things are relative to the region the camera is in, and anything that is too far away gets its distance limited to something that fits within your camera near/far

Answer (score 0):

You should be adding camera to the scene instead of to the mesh:

```
scene.add(camera);
```

And even if `cube(camera)` works, use a `;` to close the statement.